# Invalid XPath expression using Contains(Text())

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm getting the following error when trying to access a string in a table row by XPath.

```
Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//*[@id="listView-58b3-main"]/tbody/tr/td[Contains(Text(), 'admin')]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

My code is:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
IWebElement targetUsername = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id=\"listView-58b3-main\"]/tbody/tr/td[Contains(Text(), '" + vTargetAccount + "')]"));
```

Any clues what I might be doing wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPath is case sensitive. So instead of `Contains(Text())` you need to use `contains(text())`